# Assigning value to if condiotion not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, if-statement

I have var i have assigned it value 12.90 i want that if variable has value 12.90 then it may execute if other wise else

```
if (appDelegate.p_ClinInf_Yes_NV_InModel==12.90) {

}

else{

}
```

but it runs every time else statement

Comment: Try to NSLog value of appDelegate.p_ClinInf_Yes_NV_InModel before your if condition.

Comment: NSLog@(@"%f",appDelegate.p_ClinInf_Yes_NV_InModel); ???

Comment: Comparing equality of two floating point number is not recommended? What's the data type of `appDelegate.p_ClinInf_Yes_NV_InModel`?

Comment: data type of appDelegate.p_ClinInf_Yes_NV_InModel is float

Comment: yes in NSLog it is showing 12.90

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
if (appDelegate.p_ClinInf_Yes_NV_InModel == 12.90F) {

}
else{ 

}
```

Comparing a float and a double for equality would not yield expected results due to their precision.

Comment: @iPatel and others - please see the FAQ on comments: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment. Note the types of comments you shouldn't be posting (notably Compliments). Just upvote and be done. Enjoy.

Comment: Yes @rmaddy is absolutely right. That was the reason I didn't reply with **Thanks :)** stuff. Your up-votes is the best reward for me and good  for SO community.